# How to read this JSON string?

Tags: c#, json

How do I pick Id within Test from the JSON string below with C#?

```
{
  "Test": [
    "Hello",
    {
      "Id": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how I can read content inside Text, but I cannot access the `Id` by doing the same thing.

```
var test = JObject.Parse(MyJsonString)["Test"];
```

Comment: What would “the same thing” be? `["Test"][1]["Id"]`?

Comment: and when you debug your test variable what do you see?

Comment: @Ryan Thanks it works. But what does [1] do in between ["Test"] and ["Id"] ? I tried before without [1] in middle but it didn't work. Mind explaining?

Comment: `Test` defines an array. First element (index 0) is "Hello", second element (index 1) is an object that has a property "Id".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The clean way to handle JSON in C# is by using classes that represent the JSON structure and parse the JSON into them. For example, you can use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate these classes. Lets assume you have generated a class `Test` as parsing target:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; 
private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings StrictJsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
};
Test test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(MyJsonString, StrictJsonSettings);
var jsonId = test[1].Id;
```

The hacky way is to cast the result as `dynamic`:

```
var parsedJson = JObject.Parse(MyJsonString) as dynamic;
var jsonId = parsedJson.Test[1].Id;
```